# KNeighborsClassifier error (X has 61 features, but KNeighborsClassifier is expecting 74 features as input) after one hot encoded data

Tags: python, knn, one-hot-encoding

I am working on a project with mushroom classification data. The first step is to get your features/response data, split your data WITHOUT using test_train_split(), and then One Hot Encode your features data and Label Encode your response data - then run the KNeighborsClassifier (basically to find the missing values WITHOUT using the KNNImputer).

The idea is to use Column 11 (missing data is represented with '?') as your response data and the other data are used for your features data.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
model_data_df = mushroom_df[mushroom_df[11] != "?"].reset_index(drop=True)
impute_data_df = mushroom_df[mushroom_df[11] == "?"].reset_index(drop=True)



train_feature = model_data_df.drop(model_data_df.columns[11], axis=1)
train_response = model_data_df[11].to_list()

test_feature = impute_data_df.drop(model_data_df.columns[11], axis=1)
test_response = impute_data_df[11].to_list()

#Instantiate an object of the OneHotEncoder with drop parameter set to first
cat_encoder = OneHotEncoder(drop = 'first', handle_unknown = 'ignore')

#call the fit_transform() method and pass categorical data (data_cat)
train_feature_encode = cat_encoder.fit_transform(train_feature).toarray()
test_feature_encode = cat_encoder.fit_transform(test_feature).toarray()


response_label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

train_response_encode = response_label_encoder.fit_transform(train_response)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)

knn.fit(train_feature_encode,train_response_encode)

label = knn.predict(test_feature_encode)
```

I am then getting the error on my .predict() function, stating

```
X has 61 features, but KNeighborsClassifier is expecting 74 features as input.
```

I tried to add the handle_unknown argument to the OneHotEncoder, as I was suggested that this might help fix it, but doesn't look like it will. Any suggestions?

[Picture of an example of some of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF8lj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this error occurs because you're fitting the encoder on the test dataset. Ideally, you should only fit the encoder on the training set and use it to transform the training and testing datasets.

Replace

```
test_feature_encode = cat_encoder.fit_transform(test_feature).toarray()
```

With

```
test_feature_encode = cat_encoder.transform(test_feature).toarray()
```

This way you won't refit the encoder on the test dataset.

Comment: Tried this... initially got an error that the .toarray() wouldn't work so removed that. And reran all the code, and now I am gettting a new error at the predict line,  'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working. I've tried to simulate this issue using a dummy dataset on my side and it executed without errors. Would help if you could show the edit you've made in code.